# Context menu to download subtitles in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files, videos, subtitles

Is there a tool that can be added to Pantheon Files context menu for the purpose of downloading video subtitles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like [VLSub](https://github.com/exebetche/vlsub), the solutions below can search **both by hash and name** (on that aspect, more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/267509/47206)), but [unlike VLSub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049184/4098390), they can be added to a file manager's context menu.

- [the OpenSubtitlesDownload.py script](https://github.com/emericg/OpenSubtitlesDownload) - download and save it in a specific directory.

It is designed for Nautilus but it works in Pantheon Files by creating a contract file for it.

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/opensubtitles.contract
```

with

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Download subtitles
MimeType=video/*
Exec=sh -c "path/to/OpenSubtitlesDownload.py %f"
```

[image]

This script is (along VLSub with VLC) one of the most effective, as it searches both by hash and name, as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/267509/47206).

[image]

---

- **FileBot [command-line version](http://www.filebot.net/cli.html).** It needs Java to be installed.

The general command is `filebot -get-subtitles /path/to/video/`.

To **search also by name (beside hash)** the `-non-strict` option should be used.

To download English subtitles no language option is needed, but for other languages there is the option `--lang` with the 2 or 3 letter [language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#Partial_ISO_639_table), but only one language can be specified per command, so you have to use separate commands for each language.

To rename the media files (using TMDb) and match their names, a useful option is `-rename`.

The command can be added to context menu in a `contract` file; for French it should be:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/opensubtitles-FR.contract
```

with:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Download French subtitles
MimeType=video/*;inode;
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e "filebot -get-subtitles  --lang fr -rename -non-strict %f"
```

[image]

[image]

In order to **download subtitles for multiple videos at once**, put those in a folder and the option can be applied to that folder, and it will download for all of them.

---

- [Subliminal](https://subliminal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Very similar to `filebot` is `subliminal`, said to search [more databases](https://subliminal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/how_it_works.html) than just opensubtitles. That's why it takes a bit more time to search, but it may worth the waiting.

To add it to custom menu, follow the same steps as for `filebot`, but add after in the `Exec=` line the command:

```
pantheon-terminal -e "subliminal download -l en %f"
```

(that's for English)